# Is there is any way to change a checkbox's value when checked?

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, checkbox

I have a table which in each cell there is a checkbox. How do I initialize the value of each cell to 'false' (also when not checked), and when the checkbox is checked the value changes to 'true' and also the background color of the cell.

Then how do I append the value of each cell to the (req.body) to send to the server?

Appreciate any help! thanks!

This is a row I have with the checkboxes for example:

```
<tr>
    <td class="shift active left-border"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" 
        name="saturdayMorning"></td>

    <% const d = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'] %> 

    <% for(let i = d.length-1; i > -1; i--) { %> 

    <td class="shift active"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="yes" 
        onclick="change()" name="<%= d[i] %>Morning"></td>
    <% } %>

    <th class="day-part">Mornings</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes work different in HTML.

If a checkbox is unchecked, it will not return anything.

To fix this, there is a hacky solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="false" name="bla" style="display:none" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="bla">
```

Whenever the last checkbox is not checked, the first one will always be submitted.
If the visible one is checked, it will overwrite the data of the checkbox with the same name, and thus submit true.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: How can I check the invisible checkbox though? Or maybe I didn't understand you well..

Comment: Give it a try :)